# Enable 'ReaderMode' in .Net control, PInvoke DoReaderMode API

Tags: .net, vb.net, pinvoke, comctl32

I want to enable the 'ReaderMode' for paning/scrolling my control in .Net. Closest thing I found was this Win API function [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775599(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775599%28VS.85%29.aspx). However, I'm not sure how to call this one, in the documentation it says,

> Note  This function is not declared in any public header. To use it, you must access it as ordinal 383 from Comctl32.dll.

I've never called a function that didn't have a name before, can anyone describe how to do this in VB.Net?

Comment: Is there any working implementation of this anywhere?

Comment: I added an example on pinvoke.net here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comctl32/DoReaderMode.html , you just have to Call the `SetReaderMode` function when the user clicks the middle mouse button.

Comment: I tried the same. But I am facing a problem. The scrolling is not functioning as intended and the scrolling arrow remains there till I set focus to any other window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should try:

```
<DllImport("Comctl32.dll", EntryPoint:="#383", _
     CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
```

to specify a function by its ordinal. You should also pass the structure, but I suppose you know how to proceed.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. I am having trouble getting it to work though. I posted a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270046/error-pinvoking-function.